# Handling non-spatial data for QGIS projects with Camelot

Tags: qgis, python, spatialite

Most of my projects include data which is non-spatial or which is point data and can be managed by a regular relational database.  Previously I found Manifold and ms-access were a good combination that could almost seamlessly work together.  Now that I am with QGIS, I would like to move over to Spatialite entirely.  The missing piece for me is an application development environment for the non-spatial side.  I have tested the QGIS forms builder on a non-spatial table and it is quite reasonable.  I set up a viewer of geotagged photos in just a few minutes without coding.  However for the times I want to work with more complex non-flat data I have been looking at using Camelot for Python.  The documentation suggests that it can do most or all of what ms-access can do and that the coding approach required is similar.  I have not built a useful app yet, too much new stuff at once.  My direct questions:

- Have any other QGIS users developed or tried to develop complimentary applications in Camelot?
- Can you just create non-spatial tables in Spatialite databases or is it best to keep the non-spatial tables in a regular SQLite database?
- Do any QGIS developers have something in the pipeline that will allow parent/child data forms (subforms) to be created?

Comment: I can't talk to the first or third question (yeah, one question probably would have been better - but I'll treat these as three parts of the same question). For the second (part of) your question, there is no real difference between SQLite and SpatiaLite at the database level - SpatiaLite is SQLite at the database level. At the table level, if you don't use any SpatiaLite extensions, its still just SQLite. So I'd just use the same database and add tables (or columns, if that makes more sense for your design) for non-spatial data as required.